# How to use array list while using soap web service in android

Tags: android, arrays, soap, arraylist

I'm using soap web service for getting data's in MySQL server using android,I split those data's and store in array,Now I try to convert in array list.I tried it doesn't work...
Can you please tell how can i do that one?
Thanks in advance

```
public class Month extends Activity {

    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/Monthamount";

    private static final String OPERATION_NAME = "Monthamount";

    private static final String WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";

   private static final String SOAP_ADDRESS = "http://220.226.170.5/service.asmx?WSDL";

   boolean timeoutexcep=false,httpexcep=false,generalexcep=false;

    TextView m,ma,a,aa,e,ea,d,da,hk,hka,h,ha,ta,taa,nrf,session,amount,o,oa;
    EditText edata;
    ImageView button;
    String month;
    HttpTransportSE httpTransport;
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope;
    Object response;
    //SoapPrimitive s;
    ProgressDialog progress;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.month);

        progress = new ProgressDialog(Month.this);
        button = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        m = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.m);
        ma = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ma);

        a = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.a);
        aa = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.aa);

        e = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.e);
        ea = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ea);

        d = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.d);
        da = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.da);

        hk = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hk);
        hka = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hka);

        h = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.h);
        ha = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ha);

        ta = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ta);
        taa = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.taa);

        /*o = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.o);
        oa = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.oa);*/


        nrf = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nrf);

       session = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        amount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        edata = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);



        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


            public void onClick(View v) {



                session.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
                amount.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                m.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ma.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                a.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                aa.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                e.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ea.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                d.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                da.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                h.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ha.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                hk.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                hka.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ta.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                taa.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                /*o.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                oa.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);*/




                SoapObject request=new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE,OPERATION_NAME);

                month= edata.getText().toString();



                request.addProperty("Month", month);


                envelope=new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                envelope.dotNet=true;
                envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

                httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS);

                try {

                     serviceCall();

                } catch (Exception exception) {

                    /*tvData1.setText(exception.toString()
                        + " Or No Records Found!");*/

                }

            }
        });

            }


    void serviceCall() {
        progress.setMessage("Please wait...");
        progress.show();

        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                try {

                    httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                    response = envelope.getResponse();
                }
                    catch(SocketTimeoutException e){
                        timeoutexcep=true;
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    catch(ConnectException e){
                        httpexcep=true;
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        catch (Exception e) {
                        generalexcep=true;
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                return null;
            }



            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                String str = "";

                if(timeoutexcep){
                    Toast.makeText(Month.this, "Unable to connect to server, Please try again later",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                else if(httpexcep){
                    Toast.makeText(Month.this, "Check Your Internet Connection",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                else if(generalexcep){
                    Toast.makeText(Month.this, "Please try again later",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                else {

                    }
                    timeoutexcep=false;httpexcep=false;generalexcep=false;
                if (progress != null)
                    progress.dismiss();
                if (response != null) {


                    // ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>()(Arrays.asList(commaSeparated.split(",")));  
                    // al=(ArrayList<Stirng>) response;
                     //toString().split(";"); 
                    String resultArr[] = response.toString().split(";");



                    session.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
                    amount.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    m.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    a.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    e.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    d.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    h.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    hk.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    //o.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    m.setText(resultArr[1].split("-")[0]);
                     ma.setText(resultArr[1] .split("-")[1]);


                     a.setText(resultArr[4].split("-")[0]);
                    aa.setText(resultArr[4].split("-")[1]);

                    e.setText(resultArr[0].split("-")[0]);
                     ea.setText(resultArr[0].split("-")[1]);

                     d.setText(resultArr[5].split("-")[0]);
                     da.setText(resultArr[5].split("-")[1]);

                     hk.setText(resultArr[2].split("-")[0]);
                     hka.setText(resultArr[2].split("-")[1]);

                     h.setText(resultArr[3].split("-")[0]);
                     ha.setText(resultArr[3].split("-")[1]);




                    String a1,b,c,d1,e1,f,g;

                    double res;
                    a1 = ma.getText().toString();
                    b = aa.getText().toString(); 
                    c=ea.getText().toString();
                    d1=da.getText().toString();
                    e1=hka.getText().toString();
                    f=ha.getText().toString();
                    //g=oa.getText().toString();

                    res = Double.parseDouble(a1)+Double.parseDouble(b)+Double.parseDouble(c)+Double.parseDouble(d1)+Double.parseDouble(e1)+Double.parseDouble(f);/*+Double.parseDouble(g);*/


                    DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("##.##");
                    String formattedText = format.format(res);
                    taa.setText(formattedText);


                }
                else 

                    if(response==null)
                    {
                        nrf.setText("No Records Found!");
                        m.setText("");
                        ma.setText("");
                        a.setText("");
                        aa.setText("");
                        e.setText("");
                        ea.setText("");
                        d.setText("");
                        da.setText("");
                        hk.setText("");
                        hka.setText("");
                        h.setText("");
                        ha.setText("");
                        ta.setText("");
                        taa.setText("");

                    }




                                        }

        }.execute();

    }
}
```

If i give a particular date the output will be like this.

```
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
Evening-879852.17;Morning-1784588.51;Housekeeping-566652.06;Home-9585.99;Afternoon-4213060.58;Night-1768560.44;
</string>
```

If i store it in array,It shows the answer.Sometimes the evening and others doesn't appear in some other date. so,the array values decremented and the app will be force closed

Avoid that one I tried array list

Thanks in advance

Comment: please post your soap json responce in proper way.then i will help you.

Comment: I post the soap response,

Comment: plz give me json which you have got already.

Comment: I convert the asp.net database to soap url,It is not the json format

Comment: I'm using soap webservice not a JSON,It's a soap format.